# how do I close all the activities in Android in one simple click

Tags: android

I know that the mechanism of android about stacks work as a stack each one of them goes above each other, what i want is how to make it clear and exit the app with one single click.
I google it and i found some long code instead of this should have been very easily and simple to do it.

Thanx

Comment: What's wrong with the standard Home button?

Comment: it will be remaining the activities on the memory i guess and it will consume battery or memory.

Comment: Ok. Consuming memory or battery is not really a problem if you release resources properly. Apps are made to be paused and the framework takes care of that. Memory usage in it self is not a problem since the framework will kill the activities when the memory is needed. And battery wont be used since your app will not get any cpu time when it is paused. If this is your question then relax and go with the framework way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some static ArrayList and register every new Activity in it. Afterwards you'll be able to iterate over every item and finish it.

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: why this is not done by Android Developrs, :P well I know that I have to ask those guys not you here :d. btw thanx for the idea.

Comment: This will have a huge risk of leaking memory and should not be done. It also does not take in account the fact that the activities in the back stack might have been recreated or destroyed (you will have a reference to the wrong activity).

Comment: how can I creat an arraylist of activities?

Comment: i tried ArrayList<Activity> but it doesnt know about activity

Comment: Pls someone tell me about this cz the forum is gonna be offline for 30 min :S :s ...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a QUIT option to your Menu handler:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
 if (item.getItemId() == MENU_QUIT_IDENTIFIER)
 {
  finish();
  System.exit(0);
  return (true);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Activity class has a complex lifecycle mechanism. I'd read the dev guide the details at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

before trying the ArrayList route. Remember that an ArrayList is not tread safe, and Activities may be destroyed and recreated by the system at any time. Therefore, the Activities in your list will stick around outside of your application's stack, not being eligible for Garabage Collection (unless you use Soft/Weak refreneces?)

Answer (score 0):

I know of no pretty way. One thing is sure. You should not use System.exit or save the activities in a list (horrible memory leak ahead).

You could start all activities on the stack using startActivityForResult and use some result code such as RESULT_UNWIND_STACK = 100;

Then implement this in every activity

```
onBackPressed() {
    finishAndUnwindStack();
}

private void finishAndUnwindStack() {
    setResult(RESULT_UNWIND_STACK);
    finish();
}

protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_UNWIND_STACK) {
        finishAndUnwindStack();
    }
}
```

This will cause the activities to finish one after one (quickly and before becoming visible).

If you target 3.0+ you can have a startup activity that you always start through and call that activity when you finish and add the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and a boolean indicating that you are done. Then just finish in onCreate if that boolean is set (using getIntent()).

Comment: what is RESULT_UNWIND_STACK = 100; should I declare it as constant something?

Comment: Yes. You use it to identify that the result was a stack unwind. This will only work if you start activities with startActivityForResult

Comment: so in my case it doesnt work bc i have activity which start without result :s

Comment: Ok. And you cannot change that?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on the original question, it looks like you're just concerned about memory and battery usage. If this is not the case, please feel free to stop reading. If it is, I advise you to read up on the [Activity's Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). When an application reaches a point where it's no longer being actively used for any reason, the OS calls its onPause() method which (optimally) stores any needed data before ending the actual process. The onResume() method reloads any data if the activity is restarted again. This allows applications to be left running in the background with a minimal hit on overall performance and memory. If for any reason the OS needs to free up any memory, it can safely end any activities in a paused state.